# missing the following properties from type 'Observable'

Tags: ionic-framework, rxjs, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I'm trying to learn rxjs observables for an ionic project. I've made some headway, but am stuck on a syntax error that I have no idea what it means. The message appeared after I added the pipe to the http.get.

Any ideas of what is wrong and how to fix it would be very welcome:

```
TS2740: Type '{ (): Observable ; (op1: OperatorFunction ): Observable; (op1: OperatorFunction , op2: OperatorFunction...>): Observable...>; (op1: OperatorFunction...>, op2: OperatorFunction...>, op3: OperatorFunction...>): Observable...>; (op1: OperatorFunction......' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable ': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more.
```

My code is:

```js
// Ionic Modules
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs-compat/Observable';
import { pipe, throwError } from 'rxjs';

// Models
import { Game } from '../models/game';
import { GamesList } from '../models/games-list';

// Other Modules
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class GamesProvider {
  constructor(
      private http: HttpClient
  ){}

  /**
   * @summary Retrieve the full games list
   * @returns The returned games list data
   */
  public getGamesAll(): Observable<GamesList> {
    console.log('GamesProvider, in getGamesAll');
    return this.http.get(environment.API_URL, {responseType: 'json'}).pipe{
      map(data => {
        return new GamesList(data);
      }),

      catchError(err => {
        console.error(err);
        return throwError('Something went wrong ;)');
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think there is a typo in the code one character after `pipe`. Instead `(` there is `{`.